# UITextField to Enter Amount - how can I customise UITextField as in the image with conditions provided?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, uitextfield

How can I implement the `UITextField` as in the image with the following conditions,

1. The $ symbol should be on the left side.
2. The $ symbol should appear only when editing begins or if a number is already entered.
3. Should not be able to edit, remove and focus the $ symbol.

[image: Custom UITextField]

Comment: You could use an image of the $ symbol and assign it to UITextField.leftView

Comment: @Jonathan: Yep :). That is one solution or good solution, to use leftView, but not image, will need to use UILabel instead…ryt ?

Comment: Ah, yes. It is a UIView so you can assign a UILabel to it. Good thinking... Also, more than likely you could just hide the leftView when the textView DidEndEditing and show it when the textView DidBeginEditing.

Comment: ya.I did it, and is working as required.

Answer (score 0):

First, implement `UITextFieldDelegate` in your .h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Next, set the `UITextField`'s delegate to your `ViewController`.  Then use `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` to add the "$" when the text field becomes the first responder.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dollarTextField;

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // if editing the dollarTextField, then insert the $
    if (textField == _dollarTextField) {
        // if the textField is blank, then add the $
        if (textField.text.length == 0) {
            textField.text = @"$";
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Finally, implement `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` to keep the $ in the `textField`.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    // if editing the dollarTextField
    if (_dollarTextField) {
        // set what the new string will be
        NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

        textField.text = newString;

        // if the new string is blank, then set it to the $
        if (newString.length == 0) {
            textField.text = @"$";
        }

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: 1. If an amount is already entered, textFieldShouldBeginEditing will replace the entire text with just "$", 2. It will be able to focus or remove the "$".

Comment: Thx :)…above comment by Jonathan, will be one solution or easy solution…i think..pls check that too…

Comment: I fixed the code I posted so it does not replace the entire text with "$", if there is already text.  @Jonathan does propose a good alternative, which would be much less code.  It depends on what your needs are.

Comment: Ok Ron…I've used that solution but with a slight modification, to his suggestion…used UILabel instead of image.